# trying to bundle https://github.com/FaganSC/spfxModernCalendar will raise this error "Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/ParserHelpers'"

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, spfx, spfx-webparts

I want to run the following command `gulp bundle --ship` on this SPFX @ https://github.com/FaganSC/spfxModernCalendar. But i got those error `Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/ParserHelpers'`:-

```
D:\spfxModernCalendar-main\spfxModernCalendar-main>gulp bundle --ship
Build target: SHIP
[22:53:49] Using gulpfile D:\spfxModernCalendar-main\spfxModernCalendar-main\gulpfile.js
[22:53:49] Starting 'bundle'...
[22:53:49] Starting gulp
[22:53:49] Starting subtask 'pre-copy'...
[22:53:50] Finished subtask 'pre-copy' after 46 ms
[22:53:50] Starting subtask 'copy-static-assets'...
[22:53:50] Starting subtask 'sass'...
[22:53:50] Finished subtask 'sass' after 526 ms
[22:53:50] Starting subtask 'tslint'...
[22:53:50] [tslint] tslint version: 5.20.1
[22:53:50] Starting subtask 'tsc'...
[22:53:50] [tsc] typescript version: 3.9.10
[22:53:50] Finished subtask 'copy-static-assets' after 584 ms
[22:53:53] Finished subtask 'tsc' after 2.74 s
[22:53:53] Finished subtask 'tslint' after 2.92 s
[22:53:53] Starting subtask 'post-copy'...
[22:53:53] Finished subtask 'post-copy' after 1.23 ms
[22:53:53] Starting subtask 'configure-webpack'...
[22:53:53] Finished subtask 'configure-webpack' after 282 ms
[22:53:53] Starting subtask 'webpack'...
[22:53:53] 'bundle' errored after 3.95 s
[22:53:53] Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/ParserHelpers'
Require stack:
- D:\spfxModernCalendar-main\spfxModernCalendar-main\node_modules\@microsoft\hashed-folder-copy-plugin\lib\HashedFolderCopyPlugin.js
- D:\spfxModernCalendar-main\spfxModernCalendar-main\node_modules\@microsoft\hashed-folder-copy-plugin\lib\index.js
- D:\spfxModernCalendar-main\spfxModernCalendar-main\node_modules\@microsoft\spfx-heft-plugins\lib\plugins\webpackConfigurationPlugin\WebpackConfigurationGenerator.js
- D:\spfxModernCalendar-main\spfxModernCalendar-main\node_modules\@microsoft\spfx-heft-plugins\lib\plugins\webpackConfigurationPlugin\WebpackConfigurationPlugin.js
- D:\spfxModernCalendar-main\spfxModernCalendar-main\node_modules\@microsoft\spfx-heft-plugins\lib\spfxHeftPlugin.js
- D:\spfxModernCalendar-main\spfxModernCalendar-main\node_modules\@microsoft\spfx-heft-plugins\lib\index.js
- D:\spfxModernCalendar-main\spfxModernCalendar-main\node_modules\@microsoft\sp-build-core-tasks\lib\webpack\ConfigureWebpackTask.js
- D:\spfxModernCalendar-main\spfxModernCalendar-main\node_modules\@microsoft\sp-build-core-tasks\lib\index.js
- D:\spfxModernCalendar-main\spfxModernCalendar-main\node_modules\@microsoft\sp-build-web\lib\index.js
- D:\spfxModernCalendar-main\spfxModernCalendar-main\gulpfile.js
- C:\Users\mohan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\shared\require-or-import.js
- C:\Users\mohan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\versioned\^4.0.0\index.js
- C:\Users\mohan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\index.js
- C:\Users\mohan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\bin\gulp.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at lazy (D:\spfxModernCalendar-main\spfxModernCalendar-main\node_modules\import-lazy\index.js:3:33)
    at Object.get (D:\spfxModernCalendar-main\spfxModernCalendar-main\node_modules\import-lazy\index.js:11:22)
    at handler (D:\spfxModernCalendar-main\spfxModernCalendar-main\node_modules\@microsoft\hashed-folder-copy-plugin\lib\HashedFolderCopyPlugin.js:104:53)
    at SyncHook.eval [as call] (eval at create (D:\spfxModernCalendar-main\spfxModernCalendar-main\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:5:1)
    at SyncHook.lazyCompileHook (D:\spfxModernCalendar-main\spfxModernCalendar-main\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at NormalModuleFactory.createParser (D:\spfxModernCalendar-main\spfxModernCalendar-main\node_modules\@microsoft\sp-build-web\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:487:31)
About to exit with code: 1
Process terminated before summary could be written, possible error in async code not continuing!
Trying to exit with exit code 1
```

now i am using this node.js version:-

```
D:\spfxModernCalendar-main\spfxModernCalendar-main>nvm list

    14.18.1
  * 12.22.7 (Currently using 64-bit executable)
    10.24.1
    8.17.0
    6.17.1
```

any advice?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure that NPM is up-to-date.

```
npm i -g npm
```

Check version of Webpack. The version 5 (and after) is not currently supported by @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.8XX.X ([source](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/18556)).

Clean all :

remove node_modules folder and package-lock.json file

```
rm package-lock.json && rm -R node_modules
```

remove dist folder

Clear npm cache :

```
npm cache clean --force
```

To see which version are installed :

```
npm ls webpack
```

How to resolve ?

```
npm uninstall webpack
npm install --save-dev webpack@4.39.2
```

Comment: when i wanted to check the webpack version i got this errro `D:\spfxModernCalendar-main\spfxModernCalendar-main>npm ls webpack
modern-calendar@0.0.1 D:\spfxModernCalendar-main\spfxModernCalendar-main
`-- (empty)`